# How to have right click menu to copy full folder path to clipboard?:

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, context-menu

How can I add a right click menu item so that when actioned on a folder it will copy the full folder path to the clipboard.

eg. If I right click on folder `"ABC"` on the desktop it should copy `"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\ABC"` to the clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

If you <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-Click you'll see a **Copy as Path** menu option.

Comment: OH MY GOD why has it taken me so long to find this out?

Comment: @tombull89: I hope while you were at it you found the Command Prompt option as well in the same 'Shift'ed context menu. :)

Comment: yes the command prompt one I knew about, just obviusly saw but not read the copy as path option.

Comment: @tombull89 I hope you also know that entering "CMD" in a normal explorer window' address bar opens the command prompt with that current location already preset? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is such option if you use shift while you right click on folder. It is named `Copy as Path`